# Spring Boot War Deployment on Tomcat not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, tomcat

I deployed a springboot application package in WAR format. But I am not seeing the spring related logs in my console. Also, I cannot see the application running. What could be the possible reason? I am attaching the tomcat logs herewith. Thanks in advance

```
2020-07-02 17:22:17.744  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.s.narayaneeyam.ServletInitializer      : Starting ServletInitializer v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on DESKTOP-PB6GB90 with PID 17952 (D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\narayaneeyam-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes started by sachi in D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\bin)
2020-07-02 17:22:17.754  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.s.narayaneeyam.ServletInitializer      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-07-02 17:22:20.982  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-07-02 17:22:21.248  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 227ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-07-02 17:22:22.688  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4795 ms
2020-07-02 17:22:23.760  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-07-02 17:22:23.944  INFO 17952 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-07-02 17:22:24.042  WARN 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-07-02 17:22:24.172  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :

Using generated security password: 3c2c7634-78d3-4015-ab8e-c9a6c99c4b3b

2020-07-02 17:22:24.288  INFO 17952 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.17.Final
2020-07-02 17:22:25.162  INFO 17952 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-07-02 17:22:25.745  INFO 17952 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-07-02 17:22:26.474  INFO 17952 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-07-02 17:22:26.573  INFO 17952 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-07-02 17:22:26.621  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2e78fc6, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5adbbfc, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5e4ef05f, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6f946b3c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@61bb46d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5dcf9e1a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@5a5ac80e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@4fb155f8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@54779eb2, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@39715673, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6708ba7c, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@53fa3c7e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@e50c54, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@50b9a845]
2020-07-02 17:22:29.827  INFO 17952 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-07-02 17:22:29.865  INFO 17952 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-07-02 17:22:29.994  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-07-02 17:22:30.060  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositoriesà
2020-07-02 17:22:31.170  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-07-02 17:22:31.187  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.s.narayaneeyam.ServletInitializer      : Started ServletInitializer in 14.858 seconds (JVM running for 42.474)
02-Jul-2020 17:22:31.264 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\narayaneeyam-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [41,103] ms
02-Jul-2020 17:22:31.283 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\docs]
02-Jul-2020 17:22:31.316 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\docs] has finished in [33] ms
02-Jul-2020 17:22:31.316 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\examples]
02-Jul-2020 17:22:32.114 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\examples] has finished in [798] ms
02-Jul-2020 17:22:32.115 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\host-manager]
02-Jul-2020 17:22:32.155 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [40] ms
02-Jul-2020 17:22:32.156 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\manager]
02-Jul-2020 17:22:32.201 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\manager] has finished in [45] ms
02-Jul-2020 17:22:32.201 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\ROOT]
02-Jul-2020 17:22:32.236 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.56\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [35] ms
02-Jul-2020 17:22:32.242 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
02-Jul-2020 17:22:32.257 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 42167 ms
```

Comment: The logs are right there, the user generating etc. is all from your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are are all spring's logs:

```
2020-07-02 17:22:20.982  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-07-02 17:22:21.248  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 227ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-07-02 17:22:26.621  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2e78fc6, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5adbbfc, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5e4ef05f, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6f946b3c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@61bb46d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5dcf9e1a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@5a5ac80e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@4fb155f8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@54779eb2, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@39715673, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6708ba7c, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@53fa3c7e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@e50c54, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@50b9a845]

2020-07-02 17:22:29.994  INFO 17952 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

o.s.d.r.c means org.springframework.data.repository.config
o.s.s.web means org.springframework.security.web

So these are all logs from Spring's classes.

If you want to see more spring logs, just set the log level to debug in application.yaml:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.boot: debug
```

Comment: Sir I got it working, Thank you. I can see the webapp when I type localhost:8080/appname. Then I tried to deploy the war file to Elastic Beanstalk. I'm getting 404. What could be the reason? Logs look very similar. But when I copy the BeanStalk endpoint into the URL bar, I get 404

Comment: @SachinTitus It's a different question and I am no GOD to figure out why it is not working without seeing any logs . Please feel free to post a new question with all the details. I will try my best to solve. And please close this question by accepting, if the issue with Tomcat is resolved.